# Is there a typical way to disable manpages generation using autotools?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools, gnu-coreutils

I am compiling an old version of GNU coreutils(version 6.10/6.11) using autotools. However when I do some modifications in the source code directory there will be some errors when generating man pages.

As I don't care about the manpage at all, I hope the default target doesn't include manpage's generation.

There might not be a general solution for all kinds of source code managed by autotools, however I believe there must be a **typical** approach, especially for *GNU coreutils*.

Any advice will be appreciated:-)

Comment: Why does changing some code cause manpage generation failures?

Comment: @EtanReisner I guess I changed the name of the target program name and rename the corresponding name in Makefile.am; but however the error message isn't about the change I made. (I saw a lot of sed/perl operations during the make, which probably is the root cause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think building manpages is a built-in task of any sort. I believe it is usually just a subdirectory or specific target that is being run. You can probably just find the part of the Makefile.am responsible for building the man page and disable it. Either by removing the SUBDIR entry for the directory or by removing whatever target references the manpages target.

Comment: Thanks, I then commented the man subdirectory entry(and a few others) in Makefile.am, together with some configurations in configure.ac; after that, I used "autoreconf -fiv" to reconfigure; at last there is no target of the manpage generation.

Comment: This is false, autotools includes buillt in rules for handling man page tasks and includes them automatically if it recognizes any related sources.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding **installation**:

At least for projects like [Libssh2](https://www.libssh2.org) and [LibCurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), you can just do a `make install-exec` instead of `make install`.

Conversely, if you just want the man pages, you should do a `make install-data`.

I am not sure if these targets exist in every autotools project though.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the correct path for manpages not being found ,which will be mostly docbooks.xsl (as it is for me). So find the docbooks path

find /usr -name docbooks.xsl

This will list all available paths related to docbooks.xsl.

Find the correct docbooks required by make and paste it in the file